# Calling JQuery function with PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery

In MVC after successfully insertion of my Query depend on result i need to call jQuery Message Alert. and page has to reload to another Controller/Method.

Controller code :

```
 $this->model->updateSchoolInfo($data);
 header('location: ' . URL . 'school_info');
 // NEED TO CALL JQUERY FUNCTION
```

JQuery Code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  

      // NEED FUNCTION HERE - INSIDE FUNCTION NEED THIS BELOW LINE
      $.bootstrapGrowl("This is a test.");

});
```

Comment: PHP runs on the server, jQuery runs on the client. You need to put the jQuery call in `school_info`.

Comment: Is there any alternate solution for that...

Comment: I don't use MVC. Does it really make sense to use `header()` there? I thought it uses AJAX.

Comment: Yeah we can replace header with any other alternate option. I wanna call Ajax function after model..

Comment: You should call the function in the callback function of the AJAX call. You can't call Javascript functions from PHP.